# Attach PHP Variable to HTML id / Input data

Tags: php, html, database, input

simple and short.

**PHP:**

```
$test = $_REQUEST['test'];
$query = "UPDATE right1 SET right2 = '$test' WHERE right = rightprint";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="input-group" action="site_is_here" method="post">
<input id="test" type="text" value="">
<input id="post" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Basically, I am trying to update a PHP database when a user submits information into the form, it should change the data in the database.

The problem is that I don't know how to assign the value of the input (once submitted) to the $test variable, it keeps telling me that this is undefined index or variable. (All database connections are working, dont worry about that)

Comment: **WARNING**: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) attacks. To prevent such attacks you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and parameterized queries.

Comment: Are you using the same script to display the form and perform the update?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<input id="test" type="text" value="">
<input id="post" type="button" value="Submit">
```

to this:

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="">
<input id="post" name="post" type="button" value="Submit">
```

then in your php, your variable should be

```
$test = $_POST['test'];//note $test could be anyname, just and example
```

Comment: Undefined index

Comment: Are you sure you are submiting into that page?